# Serial read and send to UDP?

Tags: esp8266

I was trying to send whatever is received from serial by udp, but it doesn't work properly.
the receiver side showing number 50 51 53 ..... the result like below screenshot:

[image]

can anyone help me please to fix ?

sender sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "MikroTik";
const char* password = "12345678";
unsigned int localPort = 2390;

WiFiUDP Udp;
void setup() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  Udp.beginPacket("10.5.50.23", localPort);
  int val = Serial.read();
  Udp.print(val);
  Udp.endPacket();
  delay(10);
}
```

receiver sketch:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

const char* ssid = "MikroTik";
const char* password = "12345678";
unsigned int localPort = 2390; 
char packetBuffer[255];
WiFiUDP Udp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Udp.begin(localPort);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  if (Udp.parsePacket()) {
    int len = Udp.read(packetBuffer, 255);
    if (len > 0) {
      packetBuffer[len] = 0;
      Serial.println(packetBuffer); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. sorry I'm new to coding arduino can you help me and edit my code to working properly ?

Comment: What help do you need exactly? I explained that you should replace Udp.print() by Udp.write(). Further edits depends on what you want the code to do. You did describe that.

Comment: ok I changed to Udp.write(val) but on the receiver side only show first number of serial read side.
for example Instead of showing the number 300, it displays the number 3

Comment: Thats the part about reading up to a delimiter character. For example you could use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` for this. It is a blocking function, but that should be ok for your case. Sorry, but I won't write the code for you. There are lots of example codes and tutorials on the web about that. You can also look at the `SerialEvent` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE

Comment: Besides the issues with the code, I hope you understand that UDP is not a "reliable" protocol. It doesn't guarantee that you'll receive everything that's sent, and it won't tell you if something gets dropped.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the different interpretations of the binary data and lies in these two lines:

```
int val = Serial.read();
Udp.print(val);
```

What you write into the Serial Monitor is ASCII encoded text. Each byte of data corresponds to one character. If you write an `a` this is taken as the ASCII representation. In hexadecimal this character is `0x61` and in decimal `97`. Thats the actual value that gets transmitted to the ESP over Serial. Then you read that into an integer. SO `val` would have the value 97. Then you use `Udp.print(val)`. All `print()` functions are there for producing a human readable representation of the data, meaning ASCII encoded (Thats a standard Arduino convention). So basically you said here: "Here you have a number (integer). Print it into the UDP packet in human readable (ASCII) form." So the UDP packet now contains the ASCII string "97". You probably typed the digit `5` and then `4` a few times. Their decimal values are 53 and 52.

There probably also is a function called `Udp.write()`. The `write()` functions by convention don't change the data. They just write it without interpretation. So by using `Udp.write()` the actual binary value of the received data would be send and the letter `a` would appear as letter `a` in the Serial output of the receiver.

This works good as long as you only want to send single bytes in your packets. Also note, that `Serial.read()` will return `-1` if there is no data to read in the buffer. So to handle that you need to step up the sender code:

- Only read from Serial, if there is actually data in the buffer. You can use an if statement for this like:

  ```
    if(Serial.available()){ // read in this if statement
  ```
- Read all data from Serial up to a specific delimiter character, which marks the end of a complete message. Typically the newline character `\n` is used for that. You can configure the Serial Monitor to use newline as line ending (it then gets appended to the typed text when you press Enter). There are a lot of example codes for this on the web.